# Only certain rows on select list

Tags: php

I have a dropdown select form which is based on a "brand" table that has more than 150 brand_name(s) with corresponding brandid(s).

As you can see in the code below, I all the brands/rows will appear in the dropdown form. I'd like to know if there is a way to exclude certain brands (without deleting them from the table; for example: they are temporarily out of stock). And not just LIMIT 1 to 7.

If for example, I want brand_names with brandids  9, 27, 50 etc. not to appear in the select option, how can it be done? Is there an EXCEPT() function of some sort?

```
<?php

echo "<form action=\"chosen_brand.php\" method=\"get\">\n";

echo "<select name=\"brand_name\">\n";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT `brandid`,`brand ` FROM `brand ` WHERE `brandid`"))
{
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i", $brandid);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$brandid, $brand_name);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))   
      {
            echo "<option value=\"$brandid\"> $brand_name </option>";     
      }     
      echo "</select>\n";
      echo "<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" id=\"brandid\" value=\"submit\" />\n";
      echo "</form> \n";

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

mysqli_free_result($result);
}

?>
```

Thanks,
Jen

Comment: `WHERE brandid NOT IN (9,25,50,etc)`

Comment: If you are wanting this to work as "out of stock", you should modify your query to only pull records where inventory does not equal zero.

Comment: Awesome! That worked, Pedro del Sol. Thanks! Too bad I can't vote up since I don't have enought reps. Neither can I accept it since it's not in the answer section. Nonetheless, thanks again!

Comment: glad it helped; although as joe says if you have the amount of stock in the same db it would probably make more sense to do something like `SELECT fields WHERE stock_level > 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE brandid NOT IN (9,25,50,etc)`

if you aren't actually storing the stock level but have a list of out of stock brands

or perhaps

`WHERE stock_level > 0`

if you have the individual stock levels per brandid

Comment: Thanks again, Pedro del Sol and also to Joe for the added suggestion. I also thought of the >0 route but I may want to exclude some brands--maybe temporarily-- for reasons other than being out of stock.